# restful_authentication deployment to Heroku - Name Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, restful-authentication

When I deploy my rails app (which uses restful_authentication), to Heroku, I get the following errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant User::Authentication (NameError)
 from /disk1/home/slugs/216145_64fa92e_1859/mnt/app/models/user.rb:4
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_or_load'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_on'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_dependency'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
  ... 23 levels...
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
 from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
```

How can I get it working?

Comment: One idea you might consider would be to setup bundler in your app, then use the `bundle package` command to save all of the gems into your app. Then when you deploy, all of the gems will be deployed along with your app. Details on setting up bundler with rails 2.3.5 can be found here: http://blog.admoolabs.com/using-bundler-0-9-4-with-rails-2-3-5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! It looks like it was a problem down at Heroku's end. I contacted their support and they had to do something.

It works now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the gem "restful_authentication" on Heroku? The error message suggests that it is not present.

Comment: Alright, I've done that. Now I get this no matter what I do. I've specified to correct rails gem in my gem manifest and got the right version in environment.rb.



Rails can’t find the expected version.

Check to ensure you have specified the correct version of Rails in your Gemfile or .gems

For Rails 2.3.5 or older, you may be affected by a Rails dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm groping here, especially because you didn't put up the full traceback.

However,there may be something to do with cache_template_extensions.

http://www.mail-archive.com/heroku@googlegroups.com/msg02172.html  talks about it, in regard to your problem, and http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/66/topics/2484 mentions it as an issue when upgrading to 2.3.2.

Bottom line: find that line in your code (development.rb or somewhere near there) that refers to cache_template_extensions, and remove it.

Good luck.